# Python: Change values of a dataframe based on input from specific cells another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, anaconda

I am trying to make a schedule program. I have input from reservation IDs (index) over time. A reservation consists of multiple days. The df looks like (df_reservation):

```
    ResId 20190301  20190302 20190303 20190304 20190305     
     100      1.0     1.0      1.0      0.0      0.0        
     101      0.0     1.0      1.0      1.0      0.0   
     102      0.0     1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0
```

The above means e.g. reservation 100 is on the first three days. Reservation 101 on day 2-4, etc.

Another dataframe, which is the availability of rooms looks like (planboard):

```
   RoomId    20190301 20190302  20190303 2019030  20190305   
    1        1.0        1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0   
    2        1.0        1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0   
    3        1.0        1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0
```

So e.g. room 1 is available on all days.

Now I want to iterate over the reservations and rooms, such that the first reservation is assigned to the first room which is available on those days. So that it looks like this for the first iteration:

```
  RoomId    20190301 20190302  20190303 2019030  20190305
    1        100      100      100      1.0      1.0
    2        1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0
    3        1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0      1.0
```

What i find difficult, is to make sure that the reservation is assigned to the SAME room over all days. So it is not allowed that e.g. reservation 100 gets assigned to room 1 for the first 2 days, and to room 2 on the last day. Furhtermore, ones it is assigned, it is not allowed to change. And of course, it is allowed that a reservation cannot get assigned to a room when it is not available. Hope you get the point and are able to help!!

Thanks in advance!

In the code below, I try to use a for loopt. 'Df_stay' are the reservations (with 0 and 1). 'planboard' is first the availability of the rooms, whereafter it should change with reservation Ids. Furthermore, I change the reservations to a high number ones it is assigned (otherwise it gets assigned multiple times to rooms). I am not able to restrict the same amount of days to the same room.

```
    for res, date, room in [(i,j, k) for i in ids_booking for j in datelist for k in accommodations]:
        if df_reservation.loc[res, date] == planboard.loc[room,date]:
            planboard.loc[room, date] = res
            df_reservation.loc[res, date] = 10
```